# Finding relationships between values based on their name in Python with Panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, numpy

I want to make relationship between values by their Name based on below rules:

1- I have a CSV file (with more than 100000 rows) that consists of lots of values, I shared some examples as below:

```
    Name:
A02-father
A03-father
A04-father
A05-father
A07-father
A08-father
A09-father
A17-father
A18-father
A20-father
A02-SA-A03-SA
A02-SA-A04-SA
A03-SA-A02-SA
A03-SA-A05-SA
A03-SA-A17-SA
A04-SA-A02-SA
A04-SA-A09-SA
A05-SA-A03-SA
A09-SA-A04-SA
A09-SA-A20-SA
A17-SA-A03-SA
A17-SA-A18-SA
A18-SA-A17-SA
A20-SA-A09-SA
A05-NA
B02-Father
B04-Father
B06-Father
B02-SA-B04-SA
B04-SA-BO2-SA
B04-SA-B06-SA
B06-SA-B04-SA
B06-NA
```

2- Now I have another CSV file which let me know from which value I should start? in this case the value is
A03-father & B02-father & ... which dont have any influence on each other and they all have seperate path to go, so for each path we will start from mentioned start point.
father.csv
A03-father
B02-father
....

3- Based on the naming I want to make the relationships, As A03-Father has been determined as Father I should check for any value which has been started with A03.(All of them are A0's babies.)
Also as B02 is father, we will check for any value which starts with B02. (B02-SA-B04-SA)

4- Now If I find out A03-SA-**A02**-SA , this is A03's baby.
I find out A03-SA-**A05**-SA , this is A03's baby.
I find out A03-SA-**A17**-SA , this is A03's baby.

and after that I must check any node which starts with A02 & A05 & A17:
As you see A02-Father exists so it is Father and now we will search for any string which starts with A02 and **doesn't have A03 which has been detected as Father(It must be ignored)**

This must be checked till end of values which exist in the CSV file.
As you see I should check the path based on name (REGEX) and should go forward till end of path.

The expected result:

```
    Father      Baby
A03-father   A03-SA-A02-SA
A03-father   A03-SA-A05-SA
A03-father   A03-SA-A17-SA
A02-father   A02-SA-A04-SA
A05-father   A05-NA
A17-father   A17-SA-A18-SA
A04-father   A04-SA-A09-SA
A02-father   A02-SA-A04-SA
A09-father   A09-SA-A20-SA
B02-father   B02-SA-B04-SA
B04-father   B04-SA-B06-SA
B06-father   B06-NA
```

I have coded it as below with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

#Read the file which consists of all Values
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\total.csv")


#Read the file which let me know who is father
Fa = pd.read_csv("C:\\Father.csv")

#Get the first part of Father which is A0
Fa['sub'] = Fa['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+\s*)', expand=False)
r2 = []

#check in all the csv file and find anything which starts with A0 and is not Father
for f in Fa['sub']:
     baby=(df[df['Name'].str.startswith(f) & ~df['Name'].str.contains('Father')])
     baby['sub'] = bay['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+\s*)', expand=False)
     r1= pd.merge(Fa, baby, left_on='sub', right_on='sub',suffixes=('_f', '_c'))
     r2.append(result1)
out_df = pd.concat(result2)
out_df= out_df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
#find A0-N-A2-M and A0-N-A4-M
out_df.to_csv('C:\\child1.csv')



#check in all the csv file and find anything which starts with the second part of child1 which is A2 and A4
out_df["baby2"] = out_df['Name_baby'].str.extract(r'^(?:[^-]*-){2}\s*([^-]+)', expand=False)
baby3= out_df["baby2"]
r4 = []
for f in out_df["baby2"]:
    #I want to exclude A0 which has been detected.
     l = ['A0']  
     regstr = '|'.join(l)
     baby1=(df[df['Name'].str.startswith(f) & ~df['Name'].str.contains(regstr)])
     baby1['sub'] = baby1['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+\s*)', expand=False)

     r3= pd.merge(baby3, baby1, left_on='baby2', right_on='sub',suffixes=('_f', '_c'))
     r4.append(r3)
out2_df = pd.concat(r4)
out2_df.to_csv('C:\\child2.csv')
```

*I want to put below code in a loop and go through the file and check it, based on naming process and detect other fathers and babies till it finished. however this code is not customized and doesn't have the exact result as i expected.
my question is about how to make the loop?*

**I should go through the path and also consider `regstr` value for any string.**

```
#check in all the csv file and find anything which starts with the second part of child1 which is A2 and A4

out_df["baby2"] = out_df['Name_baby'].str.extract(r'^(?:[^-]*-){2}\s*([^-]+)', expand=False)
baby3= out_df["baby2"]
r4 = []
for f in out_df["baby2"]:
    #I want to exclude A0 which has been detected. 
     l = ['A0']  
     regstr = '|'.join(l)
     baby1=(df[df['Name'].str.startswith(f) & ~df['Name'].str.contains(regstr)])
     baby1['sub'] = baby1['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+\s*)', expand=False)

     r3= pd.merge(baby3, baby1, left_on='baby2', right_on='sub',suffixes=('_f', '_c'))
     r4.append(r3)
out2_df = pd.concat(r4)
out2_df.to_csv('C:\\child2.csv')
```

Comment: you say `Now I have another CSV file which let me know from which value I should start? in this case the value`, but you also can treat the data to get the result you want without the need to get the value to start with. it so, it will be very easy and done with very short code - confirm me if so.

Comment: I didnt get the point clearly but you should have a start point for the path. based on the start point you can find out how to go toward. this is very important cause as you see both A0-N-A2-M and A2-M-A0-N exists, when you start from A0 you accept A0-N-A2-M as it's baby. but when you go to A2 as father you don't accept A2-M-A0-N as child. due to A0 has been the father. Due to this reason i am asking to start from a path. this is the exact issue that i am dealing with.

Comment: What does this means: A05-NA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `import collections` (will be needed soon).

I assume that you have already read *df* and *Fa* DataFrames.

The first part of my code is to create *children* Series (index - parent,
value - child):

```
isFather = df.Name.str.contains('-father', case=False)
dfChildren = df[~isFather]
key = []; val = []
for fath in df[isFather].Name:
    prefix = fath.split('-')[0]
    for child in dfChildren[dfChildren.Name.str.startswith(prefix)].Name:
        key.append(prefix)
        val.append(child)
children = pd.Series(val, index=key)
```

Print *children* to see the result.

The second part is to create the actual result, starting from each
starting points in *Fa*:

```
nodes = collections.deque()
father = []; baby = []  # Containers for source data
# Loop for each starting point
for startNode in Fa.Name.str.split('-', expand=True)[0]:
    nodes.append(startNode)
    while nodes:
        node = nodes.popleft()  # Take node name from the queue
        # Children of this node
        myChildren = children[children.index == node]
        # Process children (ind - father, val - child)
        for ind, val in myChildren.items():
            parts = val.split('-')  # Parts of child name
            # Child "actual" name (if exists)
            val_2 = parts[2] if len(parts) >= 3 else ''
            if val_2 not in father:  # val_2 not "visited" before
                # Add father / child name to containers
                father.append(ind)
                baby.append(val)
                if len(val_2) > 0:
                    nodes.append(val_2)  # Add to the queue, to be processe later
        # Drop rows for "node" from "children" (if any exists)
        if (children.index == node).sum() > 0:
            children.drop(node, inplace=True)
# Convert to a DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame({'Father': father, 'Baby': baby})
result.Father += '-father'    # Add "-father" to "bare" names
```

I added *-father* with lower case "f", but I think this is not much
significant detail.

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
        Father           Baby
0   A03-father  A03-SA-A02-SA
1   A03-father  A03-SA-A05-SA
2   A03-father  A03-SA-A17-SA
3   A02-father  A02-SA-A04-SA
4   A05-father         A05-NA
5   A17-father  A17-SA-A18-SA
6   A04-father  A04-SA-A09-SA
7   A09-father  A09-SA-A20-SA
8   B02-father  B02-SA-B04-SA
9   B04-father  B04-SA-B06-SA
10  B06-father         B06-NA
```

And two remarks concerning your data sample:

- You wrote *B04-SA-B02-SA* with capital *O* (a letter) instead of *0*
  (zero). I corrected it in my source data.
- Row `A02-father   A02-SA-A04-SA` in your expected result is doubled.
  I assume it should occur only once.

Comment: This works pretty fine for one record in Father.csv, I have about 200 records in Father.csv and the code is just checking the first father.

Comment: Your input data sample (*Fa*) contains just one row. Please indicate what you expect when it contains more rows. The first assumption can be to run my code for each starting point and concatenate results. But maybe what has been found before (for previous starting points) should have some influence on how the current cycle works? Provide an example of *Fa* with e.g. 2 starting points, the expected result and some explanation.

Comment: Hopefully they don't have any influence on each other. I updated my examples and needful explanation. I think Fa.iloc[0,0] must be changed and include all the values which exist in fathers.csv

Comment: This works pretty fine. I dont know how to say thanks. I really appreciate if you just add comment to code. so i can understand it better. Thanks

Comment: I added some comments. You can also add some "trace" printouts and run the code on some limited source data.

Answer (score 3):

Commented inline

```
def find(data, from_pos=0):
  fathers = {}
  skip = []

  for x in data[from_pos:]:
    tks = x.split("-")

    # Is it father ?
    if tks[1].lower() == "father":
      fathers[tks[0]] = x
    else:    
      if tks[0] in fathers and tks[-2] not in skip:
        print (fathers[tks[0]], x)
        # Skip this father appearing as child later
        skip.append(tks[0])
```

Testcase:

```
data = [
'A0-Father', 
'A0-N-A2-M',
'A0-N-A4-M',
'A2-Father',
'A2-M-A0-N',
'A2-N-A8-M',
'A8-father',
'A8-M-A11-N',
'A8-M-A2-N']

find(data, from_pos=0)
```

Output:

```
A0-Father A0-N-A2-M
A0-Father A0-N-A4-M
A2-Father A2-N-A8-M
A8-father A8-M-A11-N
```

#### Edit 1:

Start with some data for testing

```
data = [
'A02-father',
'A03-father',
'A04-father',
'A05-father',
'A07-father',
'A08-father',
'A09-father',
'A17-father',
'A18-father',
'A20-father',
'A02-SA-A03-SA',
'A02-SA-A04-SA',
'A03-SA-A02-SA',
'A03-SA-A05-SA',
'A03-SA-A17-SA',
'A04-SA-A02-SA',
'A04-SA-A09-SA',
'A05-SA-A03-SA',
'A09-SA-A04-SA',
'A09-SA-A20-SA',
'A17-SA-A03-SA',
'A17-SA-A18-SA',
'A18-SA-A17-SA',
'A20-SA-A09-SA',
'A05-NA',
]

father = [
  'A03-father',
]
```

First let us make a data structure so that manipulations will be easy and lookups for relationships will be fast as you have huge data

```
def make_data_structure(data):
    all_fathers, all_relations = {}, {}
    for x in data:
        tks = x.split("-")

        if tks[1].lower() == "father":
            all_fathers[tks[0]] = x
        else:
            if len(tks) == 2:
                tks.extend(['NA', 'NA'])

            if tks[0] in all_relations:
                all_relations[tks[0]][0].append(tks[-2])
                all_relations[tks[0]][1].append(x)
            else:
                all_relations[tks[0]] =[[tks[-2]], [x]]
            
    return all_fathers, all_relations

all_fathers, all_relations = make_data_structure(data)
all_fathers, all_relations
```

Output:

```
{'A02': 'A02-father',
  'A03': 'A03-father',
  'A04': 'A04-father',
  'A05': 'A05-father',
  'A07': 'A07-father',
  'A08': 'A08-father',
  'A09': 'A09-father',
  'A17': 'A17-father',
  'A18': 'A18-father',
  'A20': 'A20-father'},

{'A02': [['A03', 'A04'], ['A02-SA-A03-SA', 'A02-SA-A04-SA']],
 'A03': [['A02', 'A05', 'A17'],
  ['A03-SA-A02-SA', 'A03-SA-A05-SA', 'A03-SA-A17-SA']],
 'A04': [['A02', 'A09'], ['A04-SA-A02-SA', 'A04-SA-A09-SA']],
 'A05': [['A03', 'NA'], ['A05-SA-A03-SA', 'A05-NA']],
 'A09': [['A04', 'A20'], ['A09-SA-A04-SA', 'A09-SA-A20-SA']],
 'A17': [['A03', 'A18'], ['A17-SA-A03-SA', 'A17-SA-A18-SA']],
 'A18': [['A17'], ['A18-SA-A17-SA']],
 'A20': [['A09'], ['A20-SA-A09-SA']]}
```

As you can see `all_fathers` holds all the parents and most imporantly `all_relations` hold the father-child relationship which can be indexed using the `father` for faster lookups.

How lets do the actual parsing of the relationships

```
def find(all_fathers, all_relations, from_father):    
    fathers = [from_father]
    skip = []

    while True:
        if len(fathers) == 0:
            break

        current_father = fathers[0]
        fathers = fathers[1:]  

        for i in range(len(all_relations[current_father][0])):
            if not all_relations[current_father][0][i] in skip:
                print (all_fathers[current_father], all_relations[current_father][1][i])            
                if all_relations[current_father][0][i] != 'NA':
                    fathers.append(all_relations[current_father][0][i])            
        skip.append(current_father)    


for x in father:    
    find(all_fathers, all_relations, x.split("-")[0])
```

Output:

```
A03-father A03-SA-A02-SA
A03-father A03-SA-A05-SA
A03-father A03-SA-A17-SA
A02-father A02-SA-A04-SA
A05-father A05-NA
A17-father A17-SA-A18-SA
A04-father A04-SA-A09-SA
A09-father A09-SA-A20-SA
```

#### Edit 2:

New test cases; [You will have to load the values in father.csv to a list called `father`].

```
data = [
'A02-father',
'A03-father',
'A04-father',
'A05-father',
'A07-father',
'A08-father',
'A09-father',
'A17-father',
'A18-father',
'A20-father',
'A02-SA-A03-SA',
'A02-SA-A04-SA',
'A03-SA-A02-SA',
'A03-SA-A05-SA',
'A03-SA-A17-SA',
'A04-SA-A02-SA',
'A04-SA-A09-SA',
'A05-SA-A03-SA',
'A09-SA-A04-SA',
'A09-SA-A20-SA',
'A17-SA-A03-SA',
'A17-SA-A18-SA',
'A18-SA-A17-SA',
'A20-SA-A09-SA',
'A05-NA',
'B02-Father',
'B04-Father',
'B06-Father',
'B02-SA-B04-SA',
'B04-SA-B02-SA',
'B04-SA-B06-SA',
'B06-SA-B04-SA',
'B06-NA',
]

father = [
  'A03-father',
   'B02-father'
]

for x in father:
    find(all_fathers, all_relations, x.split("-")[0])
```

Output:

```
A03-father A03-SA-A02-SA
A03-father A03-SA-A05-SA
A03-father A03-SA-A17-SA
A02-father A02-SA-A04-SA
A05-father A05-NA
A17-father A17-SA-A18-SA
A04-father A04-SA-A09-SA
A09-father A09-SA-A20-SA
B02-Father B02-SA-B04-SA
B04-Father B04-SA-B06-SA
B06-Father B06-NA
```

Comment: mujjiga, Thanks for the code but any node which contains with father wouldn't be father. As I said the path would be start from the CSV file that has determined who is father and we must go by the name in the path. your code is work perfectly good for the sample. but has bug for the 100000 rows.

Comment: I have updated my example and with this example the code is not working properly.

Comment: @SaraDaniel Please check my edit to answer [Edit 1]

Comment: Thanks this works pretty fine for when i have specified only one father in father.csv, what will happened if i have more than 1... this is just sample. I have more than 200 fathers in my father.csv file and hopefully they dont have any influences on each other and they have seperate path. in this case i just updated my examples.

Comment: It will work for all the fathers in the list called `father` since we loop over them You have to load the values of father.csv into a list called `father`. Check the Edit 2

Comment: Your explanation was wonderful. I completely understand how to move on in the path. I really appreciate the time .